# TVT Transactions - time to decision

Tags: peer-review

I have submitted a major revision to TVT (Transactions on Vehicular Technology). It has been 10 days with the Associate Editor. How much time does it usually take to receive a decision?

Comment: If it needs to go back to reviewers, then quite a long time. They may be looking for some new reviewers.

Comment: This is not specific to TVT.   Some editors only perform their duties once a week/month.  Then you have reviewers, which may not meet the specified deadline.  Also, some reviewers may refuse to review the revision.  This means the editor will likely search for a new reviewer.    There are many factors that will influence when you will get a decision.  Lastly, a major revision does not mean it will be accepted, it could be a reject once a reviewer gets a clear idea of your work.